# Flutter Looping JSON return 0

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter and after some good progress got stuck on what I thought should be a simple loop. I'm able to show a single comment from the JSON, but unable to display them all.
Below is the function where I can get and print the JSON response.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    getproduct(widget.idproduct);
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<YourDataEntity> getproduct(int id) async {
    var response = await Network().getData('/publication/show/$id');
     return YourDataEntity.fromJson(response.body);
  }

child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: FutureBuilder<YourDataEntity>(
                  future: getproduct(widget.idproduct),
                  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                    print(snapshot);
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      return Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.length; i++)
                            CommentsList(
                              comment: snapshot.data[i]['comment'][i]
                                  ['comment'],
                              username: snapshot.data[i]['comment'][i]
                                  ['username'],
                              user_picture:
                                  "${snapshot.data[i]['comment'][i]['user_picture']}",
                            )
                        ],
                      );
                    }
                    return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    );
                  },
```

below is the JSON in the request. What am I doing wrong?

```
{
    "code": 0,
    "message": {
        "message": "Détails de publication"
    },
    "publication": [
        {
            "id": 47,
            "user_id": 4,
            "name": "spadrilles",
            "description": "deux spadrille presque neufs",
            "category": "Bijoux",
            "quantity": 0,
            "size": "XS 32",
            "brand": "ZARA",
            "for_who": "homme",
            "color": "Blanc",
            "delivery": "disponible le 25-01-2020",
            "price": "150.5",
            "progression": 0,
            "discount": "5",
            "visibility": 0,
            "status": "Presque Neuf",
            "softdelete": 0,
            "created_at": "2021-01-06T14:51:27.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-01-22T10:26:39.000000Z",
            "picture1": "b7c992f0ac7b0edd7e7e5ee12e617d9c07411b4d343f64f1caf94aa08d08b8fc.jpg",
            "picture2": "efdffb16f47e0ab40788b760ab9154fc95a1fded8f6963b227aceaff302e8623.png",
            "picture3": "8e23d6ec620353c8802bb969836b5d80f6c871fdc419f695a7c1da0e71e378ff.png",
            "picture4": null,
            "picture5": "5f3eac05c317d25cd0d691d545236fb0ef6059870217ea50dfd45b914d997d82.png",
            "comment": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "pub_id": 47,
                    "user_id": 21,
                    "comment": "test test testsssssssssssst",
                    "created_at": "2021-03-25T09:40:32.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2021-03-25T09:40:32.000000Z",
                    "username": "occasion_saly",
                    "user_picture": "1611217814.png"
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "pub_id": 47,
                    "user_id": 21,
                    "comment": "test test testsssssssssssst",
                    "created_at": "2021-03-25T09:40:36.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2021-03-25T09:40:36.000000Z",
                    "username": "occasion_saly",
                    "user_picture": "1611217814.png"
                },
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "pub_id": 47,
                    "user_id": 21,
                    "comment": "test test testsssssssssssst",
                    "created_at": "2021-03-25T09:40:37.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2021-03-25T09:40:37.000000Z",
                    "username": "occasion_saly",
                    "user_picture": "1611217814.png"
                }
            ],
            "ownerpicture": "1608970983.png"
        }
    ],
    "error": {},
    "status": 200
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `snapshot.data` is one object `YourDataEntity`

Try loop via `snapshot.data.publication.length`

Comment: i loop via : snapshot.data.publication[i].comment.length but snapshot.hasData is still Null ?? how i fix it ?

Comment: Please update post code then @lucky; If I understand correctly, your snapshot.data is always null?

Comment: yes ... when i run... i get CircularProgressIndicator is display on screen.

Comment: Then it means that your `getproduct(widget.idproduct)` is running forever or is not returning anything; try and debug it